# C# string format json to json without having to replace input to double braces

Tags: json, regex, string-formatting, viewengine

I have a json template (example:

```
jsonTemplate = "{ \"title\" : \"{0}\", \"desc\" : \"{1}\" }"
```

And I need to format by an object or params. When using string format of .NET, it'll be:

```
string.Format(jsonTemplate, "My Title", "My Description");
```

And I have to change my input from single brace to double braces "{{"  .
It's seem like not good. My jsonTemplate is very long and loaded from external file or http result. So calling Regex Replace could affect my performance.
And I wonder is there any solution that string.Format could avoid use escape character or sometimes like change brace symbol which could allow to develop with json format more convenient.

Last, I'm thinking about using some View Template Engine (Razor, Spark, Dotliquid, T4...) or Transform Engine (Jolt,...) Should I really need it or I could customize string format.